# Need help creating a thread/task that runs after Main() completes

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task

I'm new to VB.NET, but have coding experience in other languages (C,C++,Perl,Java).

I'm looking to extend a piece of software that can run VB.NET code inside itself as "scripts".

I'm trying to create a background 'task' that monitors user input to detect idle time and if the user is idle for X minutes, execute the main applications session logoff and terminate the program.

The code I've written so far doesn't seem to work as I think the thread is being killed once my Main() exits.

Is it possible to create some kind of 'persistent' thread or attach the thread to the main application to ensure that it keeps running?

So:
-On load, the host applications calls my VB.NET code to start a timer that checks for user input every second
-If the user has been idle for longer than my timeout period, call the main applications .NET logoff code and close the application.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you don't explain what behaviour you're  getting and what errors you get and on what line they occur. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks

Comment: My apologies. I'll try again some other time.